# How to show academic title / degree in relational table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a litle bit problem to show the employees name with their academic title / degree. here is i attached the table :

[image: xxx]

for example, i want to show the employees name like this : "Dr. Christ Smailling, BSc., M.Eng.".

Comment: Is `fat` somehow related to "title"?  What if there are multiple titles?

Comment: of course, and bat related to "title" too. the differences between fat and bat is fat we must put before the name, and bat after name. i can add some "graduate date" column to sort the title by the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `group_concat` to concatenate all the relevant titles a person has and then `concat_ws` to join everything together:

```sql
SELECT   CONCAT_WS(GROUP_CONCAT(fat ORDER BY dh.id SEPARATOR ', '), 
                   e.name,
                   GROUP_CONCAT(bat ORDER BY dh.id SEPARATOR ', '))
FROM     employee e
JOIN     degree_history dh ON e.id = dh.employee_id
GROUP BY e.name
```